# Redirect non www to www issue

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

In fact im working on a small php script and im using somme htacces functions like rewrite but i have an problem , in order im redirection all urls dream-9.html to dream.php?id=9 using this code :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule dream-([0-9]+)\.html dream.php?id=$1 [L]
```

and recently ive decided to redirect all non www to www but i have a problem while redirecting from non-www to www the dream-9.html become dream.php?id=9 and its shown on the link this is the second code :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) http://%1/$1 [L,R=301,NE]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep rules in correct order, i.e. keep 301 rules before internal rewrite rules.

Have rules like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteRule dream-([0-9]+)\.html$ /dream.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: it does not redirect to www :(

Comment: And use the L flag to stop the rule processing

Comment: Oh I thought you wanted to remove www (as per your rules)

Comment: I want to redirect to www and also run dream-9.html as dream.php?id=9